# Взаимодейтвие контейнеров docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

В мануале на docker-compose есть пример:

файл app.py

```
import time

import redis
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

def get_hit_count():
    retries = 5
    while True:
        try:
            return cache.incr('hits')
        except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
            if retries == 0:
                raise exc
            retries -= 1
            time.sleep(0.5)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = get_hit_count()
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(count)
```

файл Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

файл docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Запускаем так: docker-compose up

1. Не могу понять как контейнер web подключается к контейнеру redis. Мы ведь для redis не указали проброс портов??
2. В строке кода `cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)` host = 'redis' куда ведет?? Где определен хост 'redis'? В /etc/hosts его нет...

Answer (score 3):

1. Если вы внимательно посмотрите на вывод команды `docker-compose up`, то увидете, что там создаются не только контейнеры, но и сеть, которая будет называться примерно так `<имя>_default`. Ваши два сервиса/контейнера `web` и `redis` будут подключены к ней (это можно проверить при помощи команды `docker container inspect <container_id>`). Соответственно оба контейнера будут "видеть" друг друга, т.к. находятся в одной сети, а "проброска" портов нужна тогда, когда вам необходимо "видеть" эти порты за пределами этой сети, например с вашего хоста (системы на которой стоит докер).
2. `Docker` поддерживает резолв `DNS` имен (на основании имени сервиса) для сетей, которые пользователь руками создал ([user defined network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)), сюда же входит и сеть которую создал `docker-compose`. Поэтому и работает строка с `cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)`, т.к. по `DNS` оно автоматически резолвится в правильный `IP`.

Comment: А если нужно ограничить видимость портов в пределах этой сети, которую создает compose?

Comment: @and_noob а зачем? вы же используете compose чтобы создать контейнеры, которые будут общаться между собой (например вы закроете redis, тогда зачем он нужен если никто не сможет подключиться), но если сильно нужно, то можно с yml файле создать 2 сети для каждого из контейнеров, но тогда возникает вопрос зачем вообще создавать эти контейнеры в одном yml, можно же их разделить по разным

Comment: Еще вопросик, если позволите. Где в контейнере прописывается резолв DNS. Обычно в /etc/hosts, но там нет redis. Откуда он берет host redis, если я пишу ping redis

Comment: @and_noob резолв DNS происходит не только из файла hosts, есть ещё /etc/resolv.conf в котором содержится адрес DNS, это встроенный DNS в Docker, через него оно и находит нужный адрес